# executing sql from vbscript which contains multiple single quotes

Tags: sql, vbscript

Executing the above query to create a new db from vbscript. This is the function that I came up with. Any other sql query would work fine with this, except this. I guess I dont know how I can 
make vbscript escape the single quotes.

```
executeQuery("IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'temp')
```

CREATE DATABASE temp")

```
Function executeQuery(query)
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=localhost;Trusted_Connection=True;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;"'
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
'myCommand.CommandText = query
myCommand.CommandText = query
myCommand.Execute
myConn.Close
End Function
```

'

Comment: Since the string literal that is your SQL command is enclosed, properly, in double quotes... I don't see the problem. Single quotes are fine in that string. What error are you getting?

Comment: I presume that the issue occurs when the passed in parameter is like this: `executeQuery("IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'o'rourke'")`

Comment: If @Dave's assumption is correct then do a `Replace(yourvariable,"'","''")` and pass that in instead